# Regex to match a string like ababba etc

Tags: regex, pcre

> Write an expression to match strings like `a`, `aba`, `ababba`, `ababbabbba`, etc. The number of consecutive `b` increases one by one after each `a`.

I'm learning regex and struggling with this regex quiz for several days but still couldn't quite get it right.

According to the description, the regex should match and fail following cases:

### Pass cases:

- `a`
- `aba`
- `ababba`
- `ababbabbba`
- `ababbabbbabbbba`

### Fail cases:

- `aa`
- `abbaa`
- `aabb`
- `abababa`
- `ababbba`

---

Here's [what I tried so far](https://regex101.com/r/mkenpQ/1/)

```
^a((b(?2)?)a)?(?1)*$
```

I'm thinking to use recursion but I don't know how to make the recursion add just one `b` after each `a` is met. So my solution also passes `abba` and `ababbba` etc.

Any ideas? What did I miss?

Comment: Must you do this using regex?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, it only accepts a regex as an answer :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [@Michails great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64751741/5527985) - I played and tried to get it below 12 characters. [With 10 (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/bVg22h/1)

```
(b\1|^a)+$
```

Still I wonder, if it works fine. It will be definetly [faster with start anchor (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/bVg22h/2).

Comment: This is it, the shortest answer, 12 characters long(including quoting slashes)!

Comment: It's really exellent answer!

Comment: @Michail It's based on your work. Thanks I could learn from your idea! :)

Comment: I didn't know the `\1` can refer to the group that includes itself, mindblown, thank you guys so much.

Comment: Brilliant answer

Comment: That is really awesome ++

Answer (score 7):

You would try this:
`^((?(1)b\1|a))+$`

https://regex101.com/r/TGBHzj/1

Comment: Interesting! Width conditional... Hats off : ) deeply impressed myself. Thanks for this one.

Comment: Wow, took a while for me to comprehend, this is so clever.

Answer (score 6):

`^(?=aba|a$)(?:a(b+)(?=a\1ba|a$))*a$`

- `^` From the beginning :
- `(?=aba|a$)` Will start by aba to make sure it starts with one b (no match, just a check)
- `a(b+)` An a followed by several b (capture the number of b)
- `(?=a\1ba)` this abbb must be followed by a, one more b, then a
- `|a$` except for the last one of course, which is simply followed by the last a
- `*` repeat this pattern of "ab+ with one more b each time"
- `a$` match the final a

Test it on https://regex101.com/r/J5rXH9/3

Comment: It is an interesting idea, thanks. But unfortunately, it passes `abba`

Comment: We can add `(?=a(?:ba|$))` to make sure it starts with a single b

Comment: Although it says the answer could be only 12 characters long. But I think I'm not gonna push it that far 

Comment: There might definitely be improvements on size :) (I mention `a$` 3 times for instance) or another way to do it, maybe with `(?R)` (recursion of the whole pattern). Could you accept the answer if it solved your problem ?

Comment: Excellent solution ++